# Calculate Time Difference in Single Column Based on Criteria from Other Columns in Tableau

Tags: mysql, tableau-api, datediff, calculated-field

I have a database table that acts as a status change log.  All timestamps are provided in a single column.  I need to calculate the elapsed time (in minutes) between specific status changes for each "on_id".  As you can see from my sample data, I can't simply calculate the difference from one row to the next since there are unrelated rows that come between status changes for a single "on_id."

```
id          state                 from_state                to_state                   start_time             on_id   user_id 
45   transition_failed      volunteer_to_donor       claimed                  2016-11-28 18:05:59.509807+00      10        53  
 1   transition_completed   drafting                 available                2016-11-10 19:56:16.454458+00       2        12  
 2   transition_failed      available                available                2016-11-10 19:57:01.199609+00       2        12  
 3   transition_failed      available                available                2016-11-10 19:58:08.134549+00       2        12  
28   transition_completed   volunteer_to_donor       volunteer_to_recipient   2016-11-22 22:14:57.060536+00       9        51  
 4   transition_completed   drafting                 available                2016-11-14 16:36:17.802104+00       3        12  
 5   transition_completed   drafting                 available                2016-11-16 14:59:56.925226+00       5        15  
29   transition_failed      volunteer_to_recipient   volunteer_to_donor       2016-11-22 22:51:01.250038+00       9        51  
 6   transition_completed   drafting                 available                2016-11-16 18:04:04.172773+00       6        15  
 7   transition_completed   available                claimed                  2016-11-16 18:05:23.30427+00        6        16  
30   transition_failed      volunteer_to_recipient   volunteer_to_recipient   2016-11-22 22:51:12.458881+00       9        51  
 8   transition_completed   claimed                  volunteer_to_donor       2016-11-16 18:05:28.546312+00       6        16  
 9   transition_completed   volunteer_to_donor       volunteer_to_recipient   2016-11-16 18:05:39.388517+00       6        16  
10   transition_failed      volunteer_to_recipient   volunteer_to_recipient   2016-11-16 18:05:48.772071+00       6        16  
11   transition_completed   volunteer_to_recipient   complete                 2016-11-16 18:06:56.9068+00         6        16  
31   transition_completed   volunteer_to_recipient   complete                 2016-11-22 22:51:38.570253+00       9        51  
12   transition_completed   drafting                 available                2016-11-21 15:11:01.842671+00       7        12
```

I think that I need a calculated field, but I can't figure out the syntax or functions to use.

For example, I'd like to be able to calculate the elapsed time for each "on_id" to go from "available" status to "claimed" status.  For on_id 6, this took 1min and 19sec.

```
id          state                 from_state                to_state                   start_time             on_id   user_id 

6   transition_completed   drafting                 available                2016-11-16 18:04:04.172773+00       6        15  
7   transition_completed   available                claimed                  2016-11-16 18:05:23.30427+00        6        16
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I created sample table and sql here: hope it helps.

```
Create table tbl(
  Id int, 
  to_state varchar (10), 
  On_id int,
dte date);

 Insert into tbl values ( 1, 'available', 6, '2018-02-22')
 , ( 2, 'claimed' , 6 , '2018-02-25')
 , ( 3, 'drafted' , 6 , '2018-02-23);

Sql:
Select distinct 
t1.on_id,
t2.availstartdte,
t2.claimstartdte,
datediff(t2.claimstartdte, t2.availstartdte) as date_diff
From tbl t1
Join ( select id, 
      (Select Max(b.dte) from tbl b where b.to_state='available' and a.on_id=b.on_id) as availstartdte,
      (Select Max(b.dte) from tbl b where b.to_state='claimed' and a.on_id=b.on_id) as claimstartdte
      From tbl a
      Where a.to_state in('available', 'claimed')
      ) t2
 On t1.id = t2.id
```

Result:

```
on_id   availstartdte   claimstartdte   date_diff
6             2018-02-22    2018-02-25          3
```

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately, I have "read only" access to the database that this table is a part of.  I could use this on the exported data, but not with a live connection to the database.  Can you think of a way to accomplish this without creating a new table?

Comment: Im not suggesting you to create a table. I am illustrating that my query works taken from the example that you give. By the way, what are you going to use to compute the time difference? Excel? Or something else? Your tag says mysql so I used mysql. Also, you did not put your expected result (with columns). It is hard for me to read your mind. Pls understand.